# Does Jetty use OpenSSL and is it vulnerable to the Heartbleed bug?

Tags: jetty, heartbleed-bug

Does the Jetty Servlet container use OpenSSL, and is it vulnerable to the Heartbleed bug?
I think it should not be impacted as it is supposed to use its own implementation of SSL but I don't know enough of what's going on under the hood to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [older Jetty docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL):

> This is an overview of how to configure SSL for Jetty, which uses Sun's reference implementation for the Java Secure Sockets Extension (JSSE).

I would imagine this still holds, though depending on your use case you may want to wait for a more authoritative answer (or ping Jetty devs directly).

**EDIT**: bumping this up from the comments below.  This question has been answered on the `jetty-users` list:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg04624.html

Comment: Someone beat me to it, The mailing list confirms that Jetty is not impacted by the OpenSSL bug. http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg04624.html